# installing fuerte on arch linux

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting the error

```
[ 98%] Generating rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp, rxtoolscpp.py 
:1: Error: Unable to find 'swig.swg'
:3: Error: Unable to find 'python.swg'
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-evan/aur-ros-core/src/ros-underlay/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rxtools.i:2: Error: Unable to find 'std_string.i'
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-evan/aur-ros-core/src/ros-underlay/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rxtools.i:13: Error: Unable to find 'typemaps.i'
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-evan/aur-ros-core/src/ros-underlay/rx/wxPython_swig_interface/src/wxPython_swig_interface/core.i:25: Error: Unable to find 'typemaps.i'
```

when attempting to install fuerte on 64 bit arch linux. I do have swig-wx installed, I'm guessing the ros installer expects swig-wx to be somewhere besides where it installed to.

Has anyone seen this issue before? What should I try to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42832/installing-fuerte-on-arch-linux/) by [es92](https://answers.ros.org/users/3126/es92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're going to need to make sure that CMake can find swig-wx using find_package.  It probably needs a CMake module or config file on arch.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0